# How to set a free strategy?

Tags: linux, memory, rust, memory-leaks, malloc

I've encountered high memory usage (looks like a memory leak) in production environment (container in k8s), and want to check if it's because of the "MADV_FREE" behaviour.

Is there a way to change to use MADV_DONTNEED instead of MADV_FREE in rust?

Comment: If you're worried about memory leaks running your code in [miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri) might help find them.

Answer (score 3):

Rust allows overriding the default allocator with the [#[global_allocator] attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/index.html#the-global_allocator-attribute)

```
struct MyAllocator;

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for MyAllocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        System.alloc(layout)
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        System.dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}

#[global_allocator]
static GLOBAL: MyAllocator = MyAllocator;
```

You could use this to change the behavior of the deallocation to your needs.

Or possably use an existing crate that impliment allocators tha logs the allocations/deallocations such as [tracing-allocator](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-allocator) or [logging-allocator](https://crates.io/crates/logging-allocator/).

```
#[global_allocator]
static GLOBAL: tracing_allocator::Allocator = tracing_allocator::Allocator{};

fn main() {
  let f = File::create("trace.txt").unwrap();
  tracing_allocator::Allocator::initialize(&f);
  tracing_allocator::Allocator::activate();
}
```

(I have no experience with these crates so I have no idea what they uses for allocations)